# JBehave: Parameters within table, such as <TODAY>

Tags: java, testing, bdd, jbehave

I wonder if anyone would know how this can be done.

I have a scenario that goes something like the following snippet.  Within the table, I would like to have parameters that can be substituted when the test is run.  Example snippet:

```
...
Given blah blah blah
Then yada yada yada
...
And the quotes should have details:
|Ref|Product|Issue Date|Maturity Date|
|<A VALID REF>|Vanilla Option|<TODAY>|<TODAY+3M>
```

So what I would like to know is whether JBheave supports this kind of parameterisation within a table where I can define a value for  and  somewhere in the code and have it substituted at runtime.

I find no documentation that refers to this, so I suspect that I would have to do it manually.  That's no problem really, but if there's a better way to do it then I'd be keen to learn.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't played with JBehave for a while (since 2.X) but it didn't support it then and I think it's unlikely to support it now.

What you're doing here is crafting a scenario which works for *all* examples. That's not really a scenario - it's acceptance criteria, written in scenario form. If you do this, you'll miss out on the other benefits of using concrete examples, particularly in the way that they excite the imagination, call out the interesting behavior and allow useful questions and conversations with business stakeholders.

In this case, if the product is the most interesting thing about the outcome of this scenario, the better thing to do is to call it out separately, e.g.

> Then the quotes should contain the Vanilla Option product.

Even more powerful would be to work out who the outcome is useful *for*, and mention in what way it's useful, e.g.

> Then the user should receive a quote by email to entice them to buy the Vanilla Option.

Notice that in the example I've given it's actually the business that benefits, and it's not really done for the user.

By making the steps at a higher level of abstraction you'll find it easier to call out the value of the outcome to the users / stakeholders, which will help you have better conversations. Conversation, *not* automation, is at the heart of BDD.

This is why I don't believe JBehave supports it, nor do I think it should.

Answer (score 0):

I think that this is what you are trying to do.

I use a lot of random data in my tests, for example, for people's names.  When I generate the random name I write it to a Java class for storing this type of data which I can then recall later on.

In the story I will have something like

```
When I create a new customer <customer>
When I do some stuff

When I do some more customer stuff
|NAME    |VALUE     |
|custName|<CUSTNAME>|
|dob     |01/01/1970|

When I do some more stuff

Examples:
|<customer>|<BLAH1>|<BLAH2>|<CUSTNAME>|<BLAH4>|
|\$random  |para1  |para2  |\$name    |para4  |
|George    |para1  |para2  |Peter     |para4  |
```

In the class where the data is extracted from the table I use:

```
if (value.equalsIgnoreCase("$name") {
    this.value = getStoredData().getName();
} else {
    this.value = value;
}
```

It is my own personal convention that I use <> around variables within the story and $ for variables where the Java code generates or recalls the value of the variable.

If you use $ in the Examples table it has to be escaped, hence the back slash